# How do I check _all_ of the issues I created, across repos, in GitHub?

Tags: github

I would like to see a list of *all* issues I created in GitHub, regardless of which repo they belong to.

Going to https://github.com/dashboard/issues/created_by?direction=desc&state=open is *not* showing me issues across projects -- in fact, it's only showing the ones in the repos I created or forked.

I have just created the same issue twice for a project, so I want to make sure this doesn't happen again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at some examples on [searching issues](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-issues)

You need to use `author:merc`

Comment: This works. However... I am really surprised that the nice "Issues" section in their GUI doesn't allow it in the first place!

Answer (score 0):

This took me awhile to find, but here it is:

https://github.com/dashboard/issues

Use the drop down in the top left corner if you want to change from viewing everything across your personal repositories to everything across repositories of organizations you belong to.

Further, since you're asking about issues, this document (which is how I found the section I linked to above) may be useful for you:

https://guides.github.com/features/issues/#overviews

I feel silly, now that I've found it though - this is actually just a tab of the page you're shown when you first log into GitHub.

Edit: Actually - I'm really confused by your question. I previously read the title and assumed you were looking for the same thing I was, but it looks like you already had found what I was looking for, given the link you included in your question. What the heck are you looking for - the link you gave takes you to what you said you wanted in your question.